# maven: Fatal error compiling: endorseddirs

Tags: java, maven

When I run compile goal on my maven project, below error occurred:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:796)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: -endorseddirs
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:191)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: -endorseddirs
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.BaseFileManager.handleOption(BaseFileManager.java:163)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:202)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:156)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:115)
```

How can I solve it?

I remove my .m2 folder and run it again with no affect on error.

EDIT1:

Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ir</groupId>
    <artifactId>endpoint</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>endpoint</name>

    <dependencies>
     ...
    <dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I test clean compile install command.

I renamed this project by refactoring in netbeans. Does this affect?

EDIT2:

When I remove build tag everything work good.

Comment: did you try mvn clean compile?

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/647049/maven-failed-endorseddirs

Comment: Could you share your maven-compiler-plugin configuration from the pom.xml please.

Comment: I've added the pom file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I hit the same problem copying pom settings to a new project thought I'd post my solution.

You need to provide a property for the ${endorsed.dir}

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    ...
</properties>
```